# How can I search the name and get result from database in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

This is the index.php page where I search name. Currently I am just getting alert with name and year of movie. I gave the movie name statically in query.php page.
but I want to input the movie name search it in database and get result from query.php and show the result in my index page , so that I don't have to refresh the page..

///updated my code but alert not getting any data

```
<?php

include 'dbcon.php';

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ajax</title>

</head>
<body>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function loaddata()

{

  var name = $('#moviename').val();

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "query.php",
    data: {
        name:name
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);

    }

    });



}

</script>

<p>Enter movie name </p>
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="moviename" id="moviename">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" onclick="loaddata()">
</form>
<br>
<p>details here</p>
<div id="result">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

this is query.php

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))

{


$name = $_POST['name'];

// $name ="rango";

$query = mysqli_query( $conn,"SELECT * FROM movie WHERE name = '$name'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
 echo "<p>".$row['name']."</p>";
 echo "<p>".$row['year']."</p>";
}



}


?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the code below i also include comment on every updates.

[here](https://api.jquery.com/click/) is the reference for click event.
Sql Like statement [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp).

index.php
you don't need to include dbcon.php b/c you didn't use it here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ajax</title>
        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            // I moved the Javascript code to head section

            $(function() // this function excited if the jquery is ready i mean after jquery successfully loaded
            {
                function loaddata()
                {

                    var moviename= $("#moviename").val(); // read moviename value and assign;

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "query.php",
                        data: {
                            name:moviename // there is no variable name so you have to assign the moveiname to name vairable ;
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                           $("#result").html(data);

                        }

                    });

                }


                $("#submit").click(function(event) // Click Event Listener.
                {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    loaddata()
                });
            });



        </script>
    </head>
    <body>


        <p>Enter movie name </p>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="moviename" id="moviename">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Search"/>
            <!-- if you want ot use jquery you have to use event listener. like $("#submit").click(function(event){}); code from line 31 to 35 -->
        </form>
        <br>
        <p>details here</p>
        <div id="result">

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

The query.php file:

```
<?php

include 'dbcon.php';

$name =isset($_GET['name'])?$_GET['name']:''; // Change the static value to the dynamic value you sent from ajax request

// Use Like statement to filter name
$query = mysqli_query( $conn,"SELECT * FROM movie WHERE name like '%$name%'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo "<p>".$row['name']."</p>";
    echo "<p>".$row['year']."</p>";
}
```

Comment: which code you didn't understand i can explain for you. only see the update.

Answer (score 0):

use like query

```
$query = mysqli_query( $conn,"SELECT * FROM movie WHERE name like '%$name%'");
```

and use post method

```
 $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "query.php",
data: {
    name:name
},
success: function (data) {
    alert(data);

}

});
```

and in your query.php retrieve name as

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not parsing movie name to `ajax.php` so first you have to pass movie name to `ajax.php` 
please update js code in `index.php`

```
function loaddata()
{
  var name = $('#moviename').val();/* get movie_name in name variable*/

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "query.php",
    data: {
        name:name
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);

    }

    });



}
```

and `ajax.php`

```
<?php

include 'dbcon.php';
if(isset($_GET['name'])){
   $name = isset($_GET['name']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($con,trim($_GET['name'])) : '';


$query = mysqli_query( $conn,"SELECT * FROM movie WHERE name = '%$name%'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
 echo "<p>".$row['name']."</p>";
 echo "<p>".$row['year']."</p>";
}

}

?>
```

Comment: please try this answer @Mirthful Nahid

Answer (score 0):

First, change your ajax call type from GET to POST
Change the data you are sending with the ajax to this

```
data: {
        name1:name
    },
```

and get it out in php as

```
$name = $_POST['name1'];
```

and what you are echoing in the php
attach them all to one variable bebfore echoing it.. something like

```
    $query = mysqli_query( $conn,"SELECT * FROM movie WHERE name = '%$name%'");
    $response = "";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
      $response = $response."<p>".$row['name']."</p><p>".$row['year']."</p>";
    }
      echo $response;
```